# How do you apply tokenization and stopwords on multiple lines of text from a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, tokenize, multipleselection

I have a csv file that contains a column of multiple lines of sentences. I need to tokenize, identify and remove the stopwords from every row of text using python. I can do one line of text at a time but how do you use python to make it read each row and apply tokenization and stopwords?
This is what my code is for one sentence:

````
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
covid_text = "i think i need to self isolate because i don't feel good :("
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
word_tokens = word_tokenize(covid_text) 
filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 
filtered_sentence = [] 
for w in word_tokens: 
    if w not in stop_words: 
        filtered_sentence.append(w) 

print(word_tokens) 
print(filtered_sentence)```

Output:
['i', 'think', 'i', 'need', 'to', 'self', 'isolate', 'because', 'i', 'do', "n't", 'feel', 'good', ':', '(']
['think', 'need', 'self', 'isolate', "n't", 'feel', 'good', ':', '(']
````

Comment: You can read csv file line by line, apply tokenization and remove stop words in each readed line independently. Can't see any problems here.

Comment: How to read csv: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html